# Call custom service inside directive angularJS

Tags: angularjs

```js
angular.module("quickquiz-builder").service("SettingsService", function ($http, $q) {
    var self = {
        'generalSettings': [],
        'getGeneralSettings' : function(){
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: "get.php",
                    method: "GET"
                }).then(function successCallback(resonse) {
                    var config = resonse.data.config;
                    config = JSON.parse(config).data;
                    self.generalSettings = config.settings;
                    d.resolve();
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.dir(response);
            });
            d.promise();
        }
    }
}), angular.module("quickquiz-builder").directive("quizbuilderSettings", ["SettingsService", "QuestionsService", "$filter", function (a, b, c) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: "templates/settings.html",
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        controller: ["$scope", function (c) {
            a.getGeneralSettings().then(function success(data){
                console.dir(data);
        });
        }]
    }
}])
```

```html
<div ng-app="quickquiz-builder">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

The code does not executes. I get error 'getGeneraSettings' function not found when i call it from injected service inside directive. I am newbie in angular, any help will be a great appreciation.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service needs to return an instance of itself.

```
angular.module("quickquiz-builder").service("SettingsService", function ($http, $q) {
   const self = this;
   self.foobar = function(){};
   return self;
});
```

Comment: Hi @doublesharp, your answer is good and working as expected. But I faced a different situation after this. Please see following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247558/angularjs-custom-directive-using-http-promise-not-binding-with-template

I will be grateful if you can help me..